# How to handle hundreds of clients accessing the same file in my website?

Tags: amazon-web-services, server, web-hosting, httpserver

I am about to host my web application.It has a .exe setup file of 25 MB size.I am planning to host it in azure or aws. My doubt is, if many of users are downloading the file at same time,will there be bandwidth overflow to the server? If so, what is the hosting environment I should choose to tackle this situation? Can you suggest some of them for me? Thank you for your time and replies in advance...

Comment: If you are just hosting a file for download, I would recommend AWS S3. It supports high availability and it may also work with their CDN if you want to push content closer to your user base geographically.

Comment: See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47089159/aws-serving-static-files-with-performance-in-mind/47095520#47095520  the advice is good for large files as well as high traffic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably host the file on S3 instead of on your web server, unless you have some sort of user authorization requirements that won't work with S3.

Ideally you would be using a Content Delivery Network (CDN) to serve the file and your web server would never see the traffic at all.

Comment: Can you suggest one or two top CDNs for me in terms of reliability and performance?

Comment: I generally recommend CloudFlare when someone asks for a CDN, but only for standard web page caching. For serving big files for users to download I prefer to use a CDN with a "push" model instead of a "pull" model. In a "push" model you will manually upload the file to the CDN where it will be stored, usually via SFTP. In the past I've used MaxCDN for this purpose. I really haven't kept up with "push" CDNs since I haven't needed one for a few years, so I'm reluctant to recommend anything given the fast changing nature of the CDN industry and my lack of recent experience.

Comment: If OP is going to host the file on S3, maybe CloudFront would come as a natural solution for CDN?

Comment: @jingx CloudFront is a "pull" model CDN, not a "push" model CDN. Like I said, I prefer "push" model CDNs for hosting large files for users to download. He asked for my personal recommendation. I prefer to use CloudFlare even when the back-end files are on S3 because it provides more features and is cheaper than CloudFront. But CloudFlare isn't appropriate for hosting large file downloads, and I don't think CloudFront is that good for large file downloads either.

Comment: CloudFront is good for files up to [20 GB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudfront-limits.html#limits-web-distributions).