# Do we get a degraded performance from S3/cloudfront after certain limit of requests?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I am building an application to read images (400kb on average) from the S3 bucket. The time taken to read them is gradually increasing to minutes. So I used a CloudFront to increase the performance. But even with the CloudFront enabled the time taken has increased after a certain number of requests.
Note: I am trying for a performance of 100rps for a minute.

```
buff := &aws.WriteAtBuffer{}
params := &s3.GetObjectInput{
    Bucket: aws.String(app.BucketName),
    Key:    aws.String(path),
}
responseChannel := make(chan s3GetImageResult, 1)
commandName := "get_image_s3"
downloader := s3manager.NewDownloaderWithClient(svc)
currentRetryCount := 0
defer food_utils_library_go.StartExternalSegment(newrelicTxn, "http://"+commandName).End()
food_utils_library_go.MakeHttpCall(commandName, config.GetS3HystrixConfig(), func() error {
    downloadStartTime := time.Now()
    numBytes, err := downloader.Download(buff, params)
    if err != nil || numBytes == 0 {
        logger.Log.Error("Unable to download item %q, %v", path, err)
        food_utils_library_go.IncrementInStatsD(constants.MetricsKeyS3ImageNotFound)
    } else {
        food_utils_library_go.GaugeKeyInStatsD(metricImageOriginalSize, numBytes)
    }
    food_utils_library_go.TimingKeyInStatsD(constants.MetricsKeyImageDownloadS3, time.Since(downloadStartTime))
    result := s3GetImageResult{
        err: err,
    }
    responseChannel <- result
    return nil
}, func(e error) error {
    currentRetryCount = currentRetryCount + 1
    if currentRetryCount > config.GetS3MaxDownloadRetryCount() {
        result := s3GetImageResult{
            err: e,
        }
        responseChannel <- result
    }
    return e
})
s3Response := <-responseChannel
close(responseChannel)
image.Data = buff.Bytes()
return nil`
```

Comment: Neither S3 nor CloudFront should have any problem whatsoever with 100 req/s, and if by chance you were pushing one of them too hard, you would get `5xx` HTTP errors, not a performance slowdown.  You should add more logging and benchmarking, don't pass up any opportunity to log an event as it occurs, so that you have better visibility of what is happening over time.  Also, you don't appear to actually be using CloudFront, here.

Comment: I haven't experienced any such thing yet after 4 months of heavy use. Hopefully AWS has needed load balancers running to keep up the performance. worry not!

Comment: see this answer and associated q&a and linked aws docs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47089159/aws-serving-static-files-with-performance-in-mind/47095520#47095520

Comment: Downloads echo "GET http://darkroom-integration-internal.golabs.io/uploads/07ff33ae-7bdb-4d14-9534-64s675aca.jpg" | vegeta attack -rate=50 -duration=120s | vegeta report
Requests      [total, rate]            6000, 50.01
Duration      [total, attack, wait]    2m1.636014735s, 1m59.979663146s, 1.656351589s
Latencies     [mean, 50, 95, 99, max]  5.004324553s, 4.716245926s, 9.644331835s, 11.154205027s, 19.202948033s
Bytes In      [total, mean]            1229802000, 204967.00

Comment: These are the results which i get when i use cloudfront!! Where could be the problem?The above code is using direct S3 bucket